# Invertible matrix and an inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all integers $a$ so that a matrix A is invertible

$$ A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 2 & a & 0\\
1 & a & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this case find an inverse of the matrix.

Using Gauss elimination method I've gotten a matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
0 & -1 & -1 & a-1\\
0 & 0 & a & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (a-2)(a+1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

meaning that for A to be invertible, $a\neq2, a\neq-1$. Because otherwise rank of the matrix would not be 4.

I'm getting stuck at finding the inverse of the matrix and can't seem to get the matrix by using the Gauss elimination method to the identity matrix, mostly because I do not know what to do with $a$ in the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $a=0{}$?

Comment: The matrix you've obtained isn't invertible for $a=0$ either. However, you must have made some mistakes somewhere, because the determinant of the original matrix is $-a^2+a+2$ (nor could there be exactly three solutions for $a$, because it's clear from the original matrix that the determinant is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ in $a$).

Comment: Take the identity matrix and your matrix $A$ and do for both the same steps with Gauss, for $a^2-a-2\neq 0$. When $A$ is the identity, the other matrix is your $A^{-1}$. Treat $a$ just as as every other entry. So $2\cdot a$ is of course $2a$ etc. (you said, you don't know what to do with $a$ in the process).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I see thank you, I'll try to find where i made a mistake

Comment: Also, if you can get the determinant as a function of $a$, then the matrix is invertible for all $a$ that don't cause the determinant to equal 0.